# Is it possible to optimize this where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Can anyone help me with this? I have doubts about the below function; can I create a virtual column for this?

```
 select as1.col,as1.col2,as1.col3 from 
 analytics.adjusted_sale_velocity
 where 
      date(as1.created_datetime)=(
        select 
          max(
            date(created_datetime)
          )  
        from 
          analytics.adjusted_sale_velocity
      )
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Your logic is fine.  The only issue is that the `WHERE` clause cannot use an index.

Comment: Is performance actually an issue?

Comment: yeah, but it goes to full table scan, kindly refer to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL optimizer won't use an index once a column in the WHERE clause is wrapped with a function, `date` in your case.

Your query might be written a little different:

```
select as1.col,
       as1.col2,
       as1.col3 
from  adjusted_sale_velocity a
inner join ( select  max(created_datetime) as created_datetime   
             from adjusted_sale_velocity
            ) as max_dt on left(a.created_datetime,10) = left(max_dt.created_datetime,10) ;
```

Try and let me know if it is faster.

Comment: yeah,  thank you it was faster than before...

Comment: It's probably faster due to `JOIN` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  It is still not [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) because of the `LEFT()`.